# Is it ok to use the same PotId as in the Substrate parachain template?

Tags: polkadot, kusama

While configuring our parachain, in `pallet_collator_selection`, we used the same PotId as in the Substrate parachain template

https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-parachain-template/blob/e0388cbb1777c1fada8e2b649360b449869ffc64/runtime/src/lib.rs#L427

It's working fine. But would this cause any issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I checked with community on element, we can have same potId.